# How to export a CSV file with a custom separator from a Banana Table Panel

Tags: csv, solr, banana

I'm using Banana above Solr, and I think the Table panel is really usefull to export data as CSV. But the big problem is that the separator is a comma, nothing else ! I tried to find in the module.js file where it could possible to specify my own separator (e.g: ';') but I didn't find. If someone has a workaround to specify the separator ';' instead of ',' it could be really really nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it around line 350 of module.js (based on which branch you're on), the line that assigns value to `exportQuery` variable:

`var exportQuery = $scope.panel...`

just append `csv.separator` parameter when `filetype` is `csv`

Comment: Thank's a lot, it works well.
As you explained I added the following code in the 'module.js' file just after the line 'var exportQuery...' :
      if (filetype == 'csv') {
          exportQuery += '&csv.separator=%3B';
      }